# Sprite kit touch issue with Apple Watch

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, watchkit, apple-watch

I am using to design some views with sprite kit in Apple Watch. Now the issue is with the 38mm watch. I am designing with resolution with 42mm watch and when I load a scene I give aspect mode AspectFit. So location where is accurate with 42mm but not with 38mm. While If I use ResizeFill it will work but the views will be clipped in 38mm watch. Another option is I can create two sks one for 38 and other for 42 which works fine but seems odd.

Below works proper with the position but gets clipped.

```
if let scene = SmartModeScene(fileNamed: "SmartModeScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            self.sceneInterface.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Below works perfect with design but problem with position.

```
if let scene = SmartModeScene(fileNamed: "SmartModeScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            self.sceneInterface.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

Another solution which is workaround is below.

```
if let scene = SmartModeScene(fileNamed: WatchDevice.is42 ? "SmartModeScene" : "SmartModeScene38") {
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            self.sceneInterface.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

So what could be a better solution to fix this?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your issue? A better workaround may be to create your scenes programmatically, or at least align your nodes programmatically (like constraints).

Comment: @Fluidity Doing it programmatically will work. But i would like to know if any other way around.